Vue ref of parent component does not trigger update of child when changed in another child (Android Chrome)
In my Vue/Vite/Vue Router project, I use a component called DefaultLayout for the basic layout of my page.
It has several slots, like action-left, action-right, title and default:
<!-- layouts/DefaultLayout.vue -->
<template>
  <!-- styling discarded here -->
  <slot name="action-left" />
  <slot name="title" />
  <slot name="action-right" />
  <slot />
</template>

Now in one view, I use DefaultLayout and put an input inside the default slot and a submit button inside action-right:
<!-- views/ExampleView.vue -->
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import DefaultLayout from '@/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue';

const input = ref('');
</script>

<template>
  <DefaultLayout>

    <template #action-right>
      <button :disabled="input.length === 0">
        Submit
      </button>
    </template>

    <template #default>
      <input v-model="input" />
    </template>

  </DefaultLayout>
</template>

On Windows Chrome and Firefox everything works as expected: I input some text, the button gets enabled. I delete the text, the button is disabled again.
But when I try it on Android Chrome, the disabled state of the button does not change when I input something neither when I unfocus the input after inputting.
However, when I move the button element into the default slot next to the input, it gets updated properly.
I suppose, this is some kind of optimization issue on Android?
Can I do anything about it?
Edit
After I struggled with this for almost a week now, only today I found out, it may have to do with another dependency of DefaultLayout:
I had defined a ComputedRef called isOnMobile in a spearate file, which I imported everywhere I needed.
In DefaultLayout I used that for conditional rendering and somehow it blocked the reactivity...
I still don't understand why, so any answer is welcome still.
This is the code of utils/mobileDetection.ts:
import { computedWithControl } from '@vueuse/core';
import { computed } from 'vue';

function onMobile(a: string) {
    return (
        /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(
            a
        ) ||
        /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(
            a.substr(0, 4)
        )
    );
}

const _onMobile = computedWithControl([], () =>
    onMobile(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor)
);
window.addEventListener('resize', _onMobile.trigger);
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', _onMobile.trigger);


/**
 * Utility to check whether the app is running on mobile or not.
 * @returns a `ComputedRef` to a boolean whether on mobile.
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/11793652
 */
export const isOnMobile = computed(() => _onMobile.value);

